# How to model a distribution from simple capital cost data?

Tags: modeling

I want to create scenarios for a simulation model I am working on. Someone recommended me a distribution and select instances to create different scenarios. But my data is limited. For example, my total data is as follows:

Capital cost #1=100-150

capital cost#2=280

capital cost#3=35

capital cost#4=42-45

As you can see capital 1 and 4 have a range, but the other two only one value. I cannot just choose, for example, 100 (capital 1) and ignore the other value. I was wondering how can I create a distribution with these values and how much uncertainty it will create? I know that more values reduce uncertainty, so how can I do this? Because I am dealing with monetary values so I don't think it will be a normal distribution, more like a linear distribution.

Comment: Hi @Moni and welcome to Cross Validated! I have edited the title of your question to make it more general so that other people can learn from it. Finding the right way to ask questions here can be difficult, but we are here to help you!

Answer (score 4):

Using a random distribution is certainly a good way to proceed. There are many good options, and only your background knowledge of the problem can help you choose the best.

Because the data is displayed as a range, I suggest that you start with the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)). In other words, you pick a random number between 100 and 150 in the case of capital #1.

As to how much uncertainty this will create, this is exactly the kind of information that you will obtain by running your scenario multiple times.